# Finding Element in NodeList XML

Tags: java, c++, xml, dom

Is there a way i can get the first `Element` from a `NodeList`?  Im using `org.w3c.dom` to handle XML files, i have already written large parts of my program using `org.w3c.dom` and discovered only recently `dom4j` which has a method for it but i cannot use it because of backward compatibility issues with my other methods.

It is critical that i can find and pass the very first `Element` in my XML and it must be of type `org.w3c.dom.Element` , however, not even using `doc.normalize();` has helped, neither did using `dom4j` methods to find the element and cast it `into org.w3c.dom.Element` as thats forbidden.

```
File file = new File("myXML.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dbuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
doc.normalize;

Element sourceElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nodelist = sourceElem.getChildNodes();
Element elem;

 if(nodeList.item(0).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
  elem = (Element)nodeList.item(0);
 }
```

Im getting NullPointerException from other methods because it cant find the element.
I need it to work in the same way this C++ code does:

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load("myXML.xml");

  XmlElement elem = (XmlElement)doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0];
```

**EDIT: OR is there a way i can cast dom4j Element back into org.w3c.dom.Element?**

EDIT2: Sample XML i need to access http://pastebin.com/C3nvxhwx

Comment: Providing an example `XML` would be useful. Does it have comments? See [my example](http://ideone.com/FFHhvo)

Comment: Yep, http://pastebin.com/C3nvxhwx